# Beginner iPhone/iPad app question

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I am a beginner in iPhone and iPad apps and wanted to learn to code(guessing they are here to stay for another 4years least).. 
I run a Win 7 PC with dual core. I didnt want to change OS to mac just for this as my games may not work in MAC :( lol
So i came across [Dragon Fire SDK](http://www.dragonfiresdk.com/). Is this correct way to do it on windows.

1. Will i get all functions to learn.
2. Can i distribute it via app store? i.e it should work in normal iPhone and not in jailbreak ones.

So before i begin i wanted to ask if this way is ok. I know installing it on a MAC is 100% ok

But i wanted to know if this way is fine to go ahead with and develop some apps for the iPhone without any worries about this being fake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (paraphrasing) Is this a fine way to develop apps?

Define "fine".  You probably can get an app in the app store* but it's not the best way, and could potentially backfire.

I strongly recommend getting a Mac if you want to develop iPhone apps, for a few reasons:

- There is an enormous community to leverage.  There are *tons* of tutorials, books, and helpful folks on SO and Apple forums that can help you if you get stuck.
- New features come out all the time (for example, the iOS 5 beta was released on Monday) and you'll have access to features in the latest beta SDKs immediately.  Third-party tools have to play catch-up.
- Xcode 4 is a pretty awesome upgrade from previous versions, and I dare say it's a joy to work with now.  But to make this point more objective, let's just say "There is very good tooling support"
- It's the recommended way from Apple, and they could decide to reject your app because it wasn't written in Objective-C (they did add a clause in their dev agreement to that effect, but I think it has been removed)

*I have nothing to base this on, except Dragon Fire's website.

Comment: I wouldn't make too much of a mention of beta SDKs on public forums.

Comment: The only thing hindering me from developing for iphone is that from where i live in its very hard to pay and get these OS or even Dragon Fire for that matter. So is there a way i can run xCode on free Linux based platforms

Comment: @darvids0n, I agree, devs are under NDA and need to keep quiet on new features.  But the existence of the iOS5 beta is public knowledge and was mentioned in the keynote.

Comment: thats kinda of a bummer. I cant get it here where i am and its NOT cheap here inn few places i do can get it.